# Mouse over on google info window

Tags: jquery

I have a google map with markers and info window over the map. The issue is whenever i hover on marker, the info window is shown. but on mouse out, the info window is not closing.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'mouseout', function() {
                    infowindow.close();
                });
```

Comment: Try `mouseenter / mouseleave`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried mouseenter/mouseleave. No luck

Comment: Can you make a working example ? Put your code in a snippet or a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this:**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 4,
   center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: 'SomeText'
});

map.addListener('mouseout', function() {
   infowindow.close();
});
```

We doesnt know your code, so, this is only a example how you can solve your issue. If you setup a fiddle, we can better help you.

**If you have already markers variables in your code, try also this:**

You used `infowindow` instead of the current `marker`!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout', function() {
   infowindow.close();
});
```

**Check also this:**

[Google JS API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=de#DomEvents)

Here you see its should be only possible to bind `markers` like your current structure means `google.maps.event.addListener(...)`

So, you have to bind a `mouseout` event on `your map` and then you can close your InfoWindow as well.

**If you using jQuery (you tagged it)**

```
$('#your-map-selector').on('mouseleave', function() {
   infowindow.close();
});
```

Maybe make your DOM is ready.

Comment: This makes sense, but OP doesn't share the original code and maybe it's something similar.